# Is there a pejorative word for a super fan?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a particular pejorative word for super fans?

People who follow a celebrity religiously no matter what, even if that celebrity does something terrible.

People who'll always try and defend that celebrity/famous person even when they know they are at wrong.

Comment: What is wrong with "super fan"?

Comment: Nothing wrong, its just not insulting enough to be used on my friends while having an argument with them.

Comment: What about SMB? :P

Comment: What about fanboy/fanboi?

Comment: A *loyal fan* is someone who will never abandon their idol, so to speak, see here: [Legions of Bon Jovi Fans Can’t Be Wrong. Right?](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/07/13/nyregion/13bonjovi.html?_r=0) Also called, by Wikipedia, [**fan loyalty**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_loyalty)

Comment: @Pip "SMB you effin Zealot!" Sounds better ;)

Comment: I would say anorak - a studious or obsessive person with unfashionable and largely solitary interests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about **Zealot** or **Fanatic**? - while both are more commonly used for religious or political beliefs, many "super fans" reach those kinds of fervor in respect of their particular idol(s).

Comment: Perfect Thanks! those are the kind of words I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Consider,

***diehard fans***

> die-hard:  strongly or fanatically determined or devoted : *die–hard fans*; especially :  strongly resisting change : *a die–hard conservative*
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/die-hard)

***hardcore fans***

> hard-core:  confirmed, die-hard : *hard–core rock fans* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hard-core) [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diehard+fans%2Chardcore+fans&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiehard%20fans%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chardcore%20fans%3B%2Cc0)

***dyed-in-the-wool fans*** [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22dyed+in+the+wool+fans%22&biw=593&bih=389&prmd=sinv&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB0Ofs36PJAhVFvhQKHYY2DEgQ_AUICygG)

> dyed-in-the-wool: having very strong beliefs, opinions, etc. that you are not willing to change [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dyed-in-the-wool)

***deep-dyed fans***

> thoroughgoing; complete : *a deep-dyed Beatles fan* [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deep-dyed)

***true-blue fans***

> true-blue: (AmEng & AusEng) if someone is true-blue, they support
> something or someone completely *Tom's true-blue - he won't let us
> down*. *They want control of the company to remain in true-blue
> American hands*. [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/true-blue)

***rock-ribbed fans***

> rock-ribbed
>
> : firm and inflexible in doctrine or integrity [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rock%20ribbed)
>
> : firm and unyielding, especially with regard to one's principles, loyalties, or beliefs. [AHD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rock-ribbed)
>
> *Among Rock-Ribbed Fans of Palin, Dudes Rule* [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/10/19/us/politics/19palin.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0)

Answer (score 2):

In Australian English a devoted fan is commonly called a "tragic", often with the connotation of life-long, and including a rather obsessive love of it.  It's not limited to cricket, or sport in general.

*Cricket tragic John Howard [former Australian prime minister] reflects on his backyard bowling in Pakistan.* http://www.theaustralian.com.au/ 22 July 2015

Answer (score 2):

I would go for **superfan** (one word without the space) or even **Superfan** (capitalized.) The term exists, and it means exactly what you want.

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=superfans prefers it as one word without the space.

The capitalized version is probably best reserved for referring to superfans of a specific celebrity/team/group, in a similar fashion to the way in which words for members of a particular religion or cult are capitalized. For example, according to urbandictionary (which is not the most reliable source but is useful for pop culture words such as this) the press used the capitalized term to refer to Michael Jackson fans aound the time of his funeral.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **enthusiastic/fervent/blind  supporters/followers/admirers/adulators**

> Definition of "fervent": having or showing great warmth or intensity
>   of spirit, feeling, enthusiasm, etc.; ardent

Answer (score 0):

A ***[devotee](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/devotee)***:

> - One who is ardently devoted to something; an enthusiast or advocate: *a devotee of sports.*

An ***[enthusiast](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enthusiast)***:

> - One who is filled with enthusiasm; ***one who is ardently absorbed in an interest or pursuit***: *a baseball enthusiast.*
> - A zealot; a fanatic.

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but re your "phrase-requests" tag, the phrase/cliché
 “**[through thick and thin](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/through+thick+and+thin)**” means:

> through good times and bad times

and is used today primarily to convey

> the idea of supporting something or someone in all circumstances.

(from The Free Dictionary by Farlex, citing ‘McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs’ and ‘The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer,’ respectively).

In your example it could be used as follows:

“I am/will remain his/her fan through thick and thin.”

Comment: I think it's fair to say that the question calls for a noun

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Thanks, you’re right, I totally missed that!  There was apparently a time (two, in fact, way back in 1898 and then much more recently in 1900), however, when “**a [thick-and-thinnite](http://historicalthesaurus.arts.gla.ac.uk/category/?id=137256&)**” was used as a noun to mean an “obstinate/stubborn person” (apparently by someone who had almost as much trouble finding the right word back then as I did today)!